# Integrating Bootstrap into Ruby on Rails 5.1.4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate bootstrap into ruby on the rails but with no success.

I am using the following gems:

```html
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

and have imported `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; @import "bootstrap";` into my custom.scss file.

I expected Bootstraps to start working its magic but nothing is happening. 
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you added a link to your `custom.css` in the layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the following?

Require Bootstrap Javascripts in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5.1.4 does not come with jquery built in, but Bootstrap's functionality still requires jQuery.

Make sure you include the jquery gem and the bootstrap gem in your **Gemfile**.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
```

Also, make sure you add the following to **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
```

jQuery and Popper are dependencies for Bootstrap 4. Read more at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `gem “jquery-rails”` in your Gemfile and then `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets` in your **application.js** file. Also don’t forget to run `bundle install after you add your gem.`

Comment: thanks, I spent like two hours for making a stupid project work bootstrap. and you saved me at last.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked after adding this line in `Gemfile`. There should be some breaking change in `sprockets` 4.0 version.

```
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.7.2'
```

Other than that, I followed instructions here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails "If you're using Rails 5.1+ ..." part.